# NodeJS gives staggered response on streaming

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, stream, cloud

So the situation is that I have written a nodejs server that consumes a stream of an external api response and pipes it to the client. I set the highwatermark to a 100 bytes so that data does not hold back and can be flushed faster. My need is to get the data to show up word by word and it does on my machine. But once deployed it always shows a staggering response. I believe I've made sure that doesn't happen from the backend, yet this issue persists. The problem is I suspect there could be something wrong with the architecture but they want me to prove it and I dont have enough conviction to. Here's what I wrote to achieve this stream, any help or guidance will be appreciated

```
  app.post("/streamChats", (req, res) => {
    const options = {
      hostname: process.env.SECRET_API_BASE_ENDPOINT,
      path: process.env.SECRET_API_BASE_PATH,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        apikey: process.env.SECRET_API_KEY,
      },
    };

    console.log(req.headers['accept-encoding']);
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    res.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    delete req.headers['accept-encoding'];
    console.log(req.headers['accept-encoding']);
    const apiRequest = http.request(options, (apiResponse) => {
      const delayer = new Readable({
        read() {},
        highWaterMark: 100, // Adjust the buffer size as needed
      });

      let buffer = '';

      apiResponse.on('data', (chunk) => {
        buffer += chunk;

        while (buffer.length >= delayer._readableState.highWaterMark) {
          const chunkToSend = buffer.slice(0, delayer._readableState.highWaterMark);
          buffer = buffer.slice(delayer._readableState.highWaterMark);
          delayer.push(chunkToSend);
        }
      });

      apiResponse.on('end', () => {
        if (buffer.length > 0) {
          delayer.push(buffer);
        }
        delayer.push(null);
      });

      pipeline(delayer, res, (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    });

    apiRequest.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error('API request error:', error);
    });

    apiRequest.write(JSON.stringify({ ...req.body }));
    apiRequest.end();
  });
```

The result shows up normally when i run it i.e. word by word. But the second its deployed, it staggers.